# How to prevent duplications with merge in neo4j and make the query faster?

Tags: neo4j, duplicates, cypher, load-csv

I have this cypher query to insert 10,000 node. This works nice.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///persons.csv" AS csv
MERGE (u2:User {mobileNumber: csv.mobileNumber})
       ON CREATE SET u2.memberType = csv.memberType
       ON CREATE SET u2.accountId = csv.accountId
       ON CREATE SET u2.accountType = csv.accountType
       ON CREATE SET u2.createdAt = csv.createdAt
       SET u2.updatedAt = csv.updatedAt
```

Now 20 new node creates [:contact] relationship with some other nodes that already exist. My query creates 20,000 extra nodes and runs very slow. I know merge has some issue with duplication. How can I make this code run faster?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///phonebook.csv" AS csv
MERGE (:User{mobileNubmer: csv.ownerMobileNumber})-[c:CONTACT]->
(:User{mobileNubmer:csv.contactMobileNumber})
    ON CREATE SET c.createdAt = csv.createdAt
    ON MATCH set c.previousIsActive = 
    csv.previousIsActive
    SET c.name = csv.name
    SET c.relationship = csv.relationship
    SET c.isActive = csv.isActive
    SET c.updatedAt = csv.updatedAt;
```

Comment: You are using [merge](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#query-merge-relationships) incorrectly.

Comment: Please help me to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're second query is wrong because you are searching for **mobileNubmer**, not **mobileNumber**. Secondly, **mobileNumber** should be a unique constraint for User. Thirdly (given the constraint is in place), this should be your syntax :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///phonebook.csv" AS csv
MATCH (owner:User{mobileNumber: csv.ownerMobileNumber})
MATCH (contact:User{mobileNumber: csv.contactMobileNumber})
MERGE (owner)-[c:CONTACT]->(contact)
    ON CREATE SET c.createdAt = csv.createdAt
    ON MATCH set c.previousIsActive = csv.previousIsActive
    SET c.name = csv.name
    SET c.relationship = csv.relationship
    SET c.isActive = csv.isActive
    SET c.updatedAt = csv.updatedAt;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom